# How can I test the presence of cookies using a Rails integration/feature spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rspec, integration-testing

My controller will set a cookie if there is a specific referral variable in any URL.  That cookie causes lots of downstream behaviors that I'd like to test using an integration spec.  How can I access the cookie?

Example of the attempted (failing) behavior:

```
describe "example cookie test" do
  before do
    visit home_path(:referal_variable => "123456")
  end

  it "sets the cookie" do
    response.cookies["referal_variable"].should == "123456"
  end
end
```

This will produce the error: 
    `` NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `response' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_6::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fa8e73f78b0> ``

I've seen controller specs use the `response` method but it isn't working here... How can I access my cookies in an integration test?

(edit: brackets)

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding cookies shall not be tested in integration tests.Inspecting the values set during integration test with debugger revealed that  the response object was nil and cookies set were empty. My solution , was to separately write controller spec to check if cookies are set, and to test rest of behavior in integration specs. 
Plus [relish cookies section](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/controller-specs/cookies)  explicitly states, that controller spec expose ways to access cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You want @response for that one.  You're trying to access a local rather then a global variable, which is why it's returning to you a name error that's undefined.  Other examples I've seen use

```
  @response.cookies
```

to get it.  Then you can extract what you need by accessing it like a hash

```
    testCookies = @response.cookies.to_hash
    cookie = testCookies['somecookie']
```

and then you can return whatever you want with that.  I'll note that on Rails version 5 you should have this variable defined locally and have it accessible with just 'cookies' without needing the @request part.